# How to mock functions deeper in the code with jest

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

Im trying to mock this mail function so I dont send mails everytime I test my code. But the mocking is not working. This code gives me the error: mockImplementation is not a function.

It's the add function that calls sendUserInvitationMail(). The mailer module export looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  sendUserInvitationMail,
};
```

this is the test code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { startWithCleanDb } = require('../../../utils/test.helpers');
const { add } = require('../invitation.service');
const { ADMIN_LEVELS, TABLES } = require('../../../constants');
const { AuthorizationError } = require('../../../errors');
const knex = require('../../../../db/connection');
const mailer = require('../../../mailer/index');

jest.mock('../../../mailer/index');

beforeEach(() => startWithCleanDb());


mailer.sendUserInvitationMail.mockImplementation(() => console.log('Mocked mail function called'));

mailer.sendUserInvitationMail();

describe('invitation.service', () => {
  describe('add', () => {
    it('adds an invitation to the db', async () => {
      expect.assertions(2);
      const result = await add(
        {
          email: 'tester@test.be',
          badgeNumber: '344d33843',
        },
        { currentZoneId: 1 },
        ADMIN_LEVELS.ADMINISTRATOR,
      );
      const invitation = (await knex.select('*').from(TABLES.INVITATIONS))[0];
      expect(invitation.id).toEqual(result.id);
      expect(invitation.email).toEqual(result.email);
    });

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In `mailer`, `sendUserInvitationMail` is `undefined`, so it has no property `mockImplementation`.

Try:

```
mailer.sendUserInvitationMail = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => console.log('Mocked mail function called'));
```

or

```
mailer.sendUserInvitationMail = jest.fn(() => console.log('Mocked mail function called'));
```

Comment: that works for that call one call I do in the test file. But the unmocked sendUserInvitationMail still gets called by the add function.

Comment: In that case, your mocked mailers could look like `module.exports = { sendUserInvitationMail: () => {} }`

Comment: that is what it is, using shorthand though, see OP.

Comment: @RobIndesteege Does it work if you provide the implementation to `jest.mock`? – `jest.mock(..., () => ({ sendUserInvitationMail: jest.fn(...) }))`